# How add attribute to radio element on new items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, checked

The code can add attribute checked="checked" on first item already loaded from HTML markup. But, when I added a new "item" radio element, the code cannot include the attribute checked="checked". Why this happens?

I tested using the browser console (F12) to see if attribute would be included or not on respective radio input clicked, but no success so far.

If I not add checked="checked" my value is not stored on sql table. But if I add checked="checked" manually, editing on my browser console, my value is updated with success on sql table.

How can I fix this situation?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrfog/315gkvxt/40/)

```
<div id="p_scents">
<p>
<span class="custom_radio">
<input type="radio" id="featured-1" name="s_radio" value="1"> <label for="featured-1">item 1</label>
</span>
</p>    
</div>
<span id="add" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">add</span>
<span id="remove" class="btn btn-sm btn-pub">remove</span>

var i = 1 ;
var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
function add_track() {
  if(i < 30){       
  i++;  
  $('<p><span class="custom_radio"><input type="radio" id="featured-'+ i +'" name="s_radio" value="'+ i +'"> <label for="featured-'+ i +'">item '+ i +'</label></span></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);  
  }
}

function remove_track() {
  if(i > 1){            
  var select = document.getElementById('p_scents');
  select.removeChild(select.lastChild); 
  i--;
  }
}

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', add_track, false);
document.getElementById('remove').addEventListener('click', remove_track, false);

$("[name='s_radio']").on("click", function() {
    $("[name='s_radio']").attr("checked", false);
    $(this).attr("checked", true);
});
```

Comment: Exactly, he only can check the item 1 (very sad). That piece of code is supposed add checked="checked" or remove last checked="checked" of previous item clicked, and add on current item = checked. I meant, when you click on label of a radio input he need uncheck the last check of previous item checked. The problem is it not working with new items added via append. I think, it need some trick, but no ideias so far. Ohhh... I see now you delete your comment. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: `$("[name='s_radio']").on("click".`  is completely unnecessary, your logic inside is what HTML radio button does itself with no JS at all needed. And where exactly you can "not" add `checked="checked"`, in what p/art of code? What are you talking about? And if you want to add events to dynamically added elements use: `$("document").on("click", "[name='s_radio']", function() {` This will bind the event to document, and then look for all `[name='s_radio']` no matter when added. Btw just add  `checked="checked"` to your add_track new element!

Comment: There is no trick here, it's only because the event listener is added for the already existed input elements with the name `"s_radio"`, but for future ones they have no event listener for the click

Comment: And changing the status of checked is done automatically by the browser for the same name radio type input elements, I don't know why do you want to write code for that?!

Comment: Yes, «for the future ones they have no event listener for the click». That is my problem. Yes, I need add attribute checked="checked". A lot of people have problems with radio or checkbox, is not coincidence. Really, I need it, or I cant update my value on sql table. Please, give me some help on this.

Comment: Read my comment, you have everything there, there is nothing to add. And no, "people" have no problems with radio buttons.

Comment: Well just add an event listener to each created input element, write this `.on("click", function(e) {
    $("[name='s_radio']").attr("checked", false);
    $(e.target).attr("checked", true);
}); ` after `.appendTo(scntDiv)` inside your `add_track()` function

Comment: I want write code to do that, because browser is not my friend with that. Really, with that is impossible update my value on sql column.

Comment: Why you put code here by message? I'm not a expert, I just need see a complete code detailed really working as main answer, and not a short message. Sorry, but I don't know what I read here... is a mess with short messages. I hope you not see me as arrogant guy. I'm not that. I'm a simple guy trying find a simple solution to my current problem.

Comment: ikiK, I don't have everything here. I have fragments of code trying explain to me how to do. I'm not a expert, I need a fully function or code complete to try see if will works to my side. Thanks if you really can really do it.

Comment: ikiK, I cant do that: « just add checked="checked"», because last item will count as checked if all items are "checked" by default. I just need one checked clicked by user..

Comment: SaymoinSam, Thank you very much, it working very well with your code!! All good man :D

Comment: @ikiK, check my temporary answer. And thanks about your info.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should solve the problem

```
$(document).on('click',"[name='s_radio']",function (e) {
    $("[name='s_radio']").attr("checked", false);
    $(this).attr("checked", true);
})
```

Comment: Thank you it works very well like @SaymoinSam code too :D

Comment: While answers may solve the problem formatted like his  are not welcomed on SO, you should explain why will this solve the problem so OP actually learns something in process.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clarify few things here so you actually learn something:

1. you are writing the JS code for something HTML radio buttons do them self's. If you put same `name` attribute in your case `name="s_radio"` on them they will automatically uncheck others and just live check on the only clicked one, they just need to have same `name`, and you already did that. This is called grouping inputs:

**Example:**

```js
var i = 1 ;
var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
function add_track() {
  if(i < 30){       
  i++;  
  $('<p><span class="custom_radio"><input type="radio" id="featured-'+ i +'" name="s_radio" value="'+ i +'"> <label for="featured-'+ i +'">item '+ i +'</label></span></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);  
  }
}

function remove_track() {
  if(i > 1){            
  var select = document.getElementById('p_scents');
  select.removeChild(select.lastChild); 
  i--;
  }
}

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', add_track, false);
document.getElementById('remove').addEventListener('click', remove_track, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="p_scents">
<p>
<span class="custom_radio">
<input type="radio" id="featured-1" name="s_radio" value="1"> <label for="featured-1">item 1</label>
</span>
</p>    
</div>
<span id="add" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">add</span>
<span id="remove" class="btn btn-sm btn-pub">remove</span>
```

So your JS code is complicity unnecessary as HTML will do this for you alone... And it was clearly stated in comments.

2. You are adding your JS click event listener on page load and it creates a list of elements on page load. You are adding more of them with button and they will not be included in that list. So solution is to bound listener on document itself and when clicked it will check for all elements with added selector.

So do not use `$("[name='s_radio']").on("click", function() {` where you target just already loaded `[name='s_radio']` radios

Use `$("document").on("click", "[name='s_radio']", function() {` where you will bind document and on click it will check for all  `[name='s_radio']`, new or old. By new I talk about dynamically added with button.

So people do not have problems with radio buttons, Id say radios have problem with some people. And browser IS your friend. You just need to learn to use it.